# Listview - list items updated with fetched data in background

Tags: android

Currently i am having listview with multiple items (First time, i fetch data with the use of AsyncTask), now i want to implement the below functionalities:

I am showing Option Dialog(With options Edit, Delete, Read) whenever user do long-click  on any item, now if user select "Delete" option, at that time i want to remove item from the listview, listview should be displayed without that item meanwhile the data should also be fetched(in background) from the web.

Anybody knows, how do i implement such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the action of delete, delete the data from the source array, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter. and from the place where you call `notifyDataSetChanged`, you can do all the web stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Use `notifyDataSetChanged()` over your `Adapter`

Comment: ya that i know we can refresh the listview by implementing notifyDataSetChanged() method, but i am in search of example of listview with all search operations, because i know all these methods and meaning of it, but dont know the actual practical implementation. Thanx for the support.

Comment: Please see the example here  https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Threads/Asyncer/.  I think this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

For display a dialog box when log press of listview item use onContextMenu() method in that onContextmenu u use the listview object and in that contaxt menu u write the code for display a dialog box with 3 options and next one remove item from listview when u click on the delete button in that dialog box is in delete button click listener remove the item from the listview and again set that remaining elements to that listview.